# How to get full news content from News API

Tags: android, json, api

[image][image: This is how I parse the JSON **strong text**]

I'm using google news API to get news for my news App(Android). But the problem is, it only provides a short description of  the news. Is there a way to get the full news content. The Screen Shot of the

1. Parse the JSON
2. Is how I set a onItem clicklistner to go to the website when click on the news item .

But I want to get the full news content in my app. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Comment: It‘s always helpful to provide some code to understand the context better.

Comment: Im not familiar with News API but somehow they must be providing you with the url to the news content, so if you want full news content you just need to go to that url.

Comment: they can't give you the full news because those are not their news, they take them from external sources like nbc news , wci , etc.... , they give you description and the link of full article with description and image

Comment: Badran I know that they are providing a short desciption and the link to the full article but there are so many app Like Dailyhunt and other news app , in which you can read the whole news. I want to do the samething in my app

Comment: You're basically asking how to parse the content of the `URL` from the link the first API gives you, which is far too broad as every news website has its own format.

Comment: cricket_007 I'm usnig newsapi.org(Google news api), can you help me how to parse the content from the url given by the api and show the news content in my app.

Comment: Just pay for it

Comment: Aylien provides a News API that gives you access to NLP-enriched news articles from 80,000+ news sources: https://aylien.com/product/news-api/demo

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a way to do that it's just included in the paid version. On NewsAPI it says 
The unformatted content of the article, where available. This is truncated to 260 chars for Developer plan users.
[Evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyRvS.png)

Where does it say this? Right here at the bottom of the page under "content": https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines

I've been trying to develop a news app too.

Comment: seems like this option is not available any more . Just checked out your link from the newsapi and now the explanation of the content has been changed

Comment: I'm trying also :-/ - came across this comment in another question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55571391/9872985